# UITableViewCell Resign FirstResponder

Tags: iphone

---

Hi,

I have a UIViewController class that contains a UITableViewCell subclass.

Within the tableViewCell I have a UITextView that calls the numberPad which I have ammended to contain the missing DONE button.

THe DONE button, when pressed calls a method named backgroundPressed. This method is called from the root UIViewController class.

```
-(IBAction)backgroundPressed:(id)sender{

[textField2 resignFirstResponder];
```

The problem I have is that calling this method does not dismiss the numberPad. This is probably because the method is called from the UIViewContoller class. How do I access
the UITableViewCell to resign the first responder when the for the UITextView?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This should work.  Does textField2 have a valid reference to the textField?  I presume that your UITableViewCell is a custom object are you saving a reference to either the cell object or the textfield?

```
[myCellObject.textField2 resignFirstResponder]
// or
[self.textField2 resignFirstResponder]    // should work if you have a valid reference
```

Comment: Yes I have a reference in the UITableViewCell class named SubtitleCellController *subtitleCellController. I've added [subtitleCellController.textField2 resignFirstResponder] but this doesnt dismiss the numberPad.